# How can I centrally control and maintain python installations and modules across multiple machines?

Tags: python, version-control, anaconda

I'm interested in rolling out Python to multiple machines as an admin user as well as having a single admin controlled source for Python modules that users can access from their individual machines.

I would also like to be able to maintain and update python installations and modules to standardise versions accessed by each user.

How can I go about undertaking this?

Comment: Have you tried https://www.fabfile.org/? It makes it possible to send the same command to multiple ssh endpoints

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [virtual envs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) to do that. They allow you to create isolated Python environments where you can easily manage dependencies.

This would no prevent the users to use different versions of the modules, but they could easily get the version you want them to have.